# How do I remove previously download apps from my Google Play account?

Tags: google-play-store

When I click on "My orders and settings" it shows me all the apps I've ever installed, including ones I've deleted from my phone. I would like for apps I've uninstalled to not appear in this list. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix that for yourself:

- open the playstore app
- navigate to *Menu→My Apps*
- chose the "All" tab
- next to the apps you've no longer installed, you'll find a symbol looking like a striked circle ("parking forbidden here"). Long-tap that for the first app you want to get rid off here.
- at the top of the page you should find a notice that you've marked one app. Now tap all other apps you want removed from the list to mark them.
- having all marked, tap on "remove" there

Done.